# How to track memory leaks using codeduitests?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have coded ui tests for standalone application. I think that we have memory leaks.

Does anybody have any ideas how to catch this using coded ui?
I know that we don't have any build-in feature to do this but maybe somebody faced the same problem before...

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful that you can effectively find everything without hand-coding. Very simplified scenario - open and close one form for thousand times(suppose we talk about winforms) and hoping to get `outofmemory`, already requires cycle to call some automated script thousand times. Not to speak of more sophisticated scenarios - forcing garbage collection after each closing.

Answer (score 0):

Coded ui tests is not the right tool for finding memory leaks. 
You need to run profiling tools to identify memory leaks. You can use the visual studio profiler or other tools like ANTs Or .Net memory profiler (http://memprofiler.com/)